# How to add a custom image/icon in ant design Avatar?

Tags: relative-path, antd

In Ant design version 4, Avatar Absolute link images are working, but relative link images are not working?

This below absolute link working

`<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />`

but relative link not working, like below

`<Avatar src="./icons/user.png" />`

Comment: have you checkd in your inspect image is load or not ?

Comment: I checked in inspect, but an image is not loading

Answer (score 3):

For local resources, you have to rely on webpack file-loader, the reason is webpack move stuff around, I don't know if you are using CRA or webpack, but usually is

```
import userPng from './icons/user.png';

<Avatar src={userPng} />
```